# Refreshing desktop screen using a command line

Tags: command-line

I want to refresh the desktop screen after having changed the desktop repertory with a "mount --bind" command (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Thanks for any help.

Arbiel

---

Thank you for your help.

However

1) unity's manpage states
"  --replace
              Deprecated option for backwards compatibility.  Has no effect."
Is there any other long term solution ?

2) the command closes the session and returns to the login screen, requesting the keying in of the password, even if the unique user's profile contains a "automatic connection" option. I'm looking for a way to save either the closing and reopening of the session or the keying in of the password.

Arbiel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to terminal and 
    type

> unity --replace

Press the Enter key

Comment: Hi Jacob. This works

Comment: BTW do not use this when using multiple desktop environments! It will mess them up. ex: If you were using KDE and typed this, it would add all the unity stuff over top of it. Like the launcher.